# Octopress - Generating blank files

Tags: octopress

Asked this on superuser.com, not sure if stackoverflow is a better suitable place for it, but I am not getting any answers yet:

===

I am trying to generate a new blog entry in my octopress setup, but I noticed that some previous posts are being generated as empty files in public, so are the new ones I am trying to generte.

There seems to be no difference at all between the markup files from one entry which is being properly generated to another that isn't

I've got two octopress installations, one's working and this one I am talking about isn't, updates octopress on both, reinstalled bundle but no luck, files as atom.xml are also not being generated correctly.

Also updated from ruby 1.9.2p290 to latest release from 1.9.3 but also did not difference.

Anyone's encountered this before?

===

Comment: What Markdown engine are you using, and do you have an updated version of the relevant gem? Typically it's the maruku gem - another user had the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920602/octopress-generating-0kb-html-files

Comment: This is happening to me on Windows with kramdown as the markdown engine. I'll reply if I figure out what's causing this but so far no dice. Markdown-applied pages generate in `public/` as empty (0 kB) files. I ran the kramdown CLI app directly on a particular post and it did generate the correct HTML though.

Answer (score 8):

This is most likely because you started using codeblocks. This was happening to me, and even posts/pages that didn't use codeblocks would fail to generate. My problem (on Windows) was that I didn't even have Python installed (thought I did). Installing it fixed the problem, then gave me another error, which was fixed by updating the `pygments.rb` (note `.rb`) gem. Doing these two things fixed all my problems.

There's a similar issue if you're on arch linux which defaults python to version 3 which isn't supported by `pygments.rb` yet. You'll have to look around to figure out how to fix that to use 2.7 instead, but it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: This happened to me once when Python was accidentally removed from the path. It started working after adding back.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example of: a) a post that *doesn't* generate correctly, and b) a post that *does* generate correctly?

I assume they are just individual posts (and not, for example, pages like /about/). I would also assume that they render as blank both in the blog index on your front page *and* on the individual post page.

Also - what *does* render? Is it rendering the rest of the page, but just without the "content" of the post itself? Or does the page not even exist? (404?)

Comment: It renders nothing, generated files are 0 byte in size. What I did is just to author in a linux box, I had no time to dig in more and find the cause of the problem. The curious thing is that javascript files and css files are in fact generated but I supposed they are since they are processed differently. Thanks for answering though, I was considering to close this question.

Comment: @jgemedina Check what version of maruku you are using on each machine.

Comment: answering you and [elithrar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/556573/elithrar) on both machines maruku is 0.6.0 not sure what could be causing that.